# Parallel computing issues when running a Module

Tags: parallelization, scoping

I'm running a heavy simulation and try to use Parallel computing to run a Module case. I have been working on this parallel computation for more than three months, but still haven't come up with a solution with my code.

I most function I'm trying is Parallelize, DistributeDefinitions, I put every effort I can but still don't know how to make this works. I show a part of my code here, for instance, anyone can give me some advice? Many Thanks and happy new year.

```
LaunchKernels[];
sPa[s_, r_, n_Integer?Positive, tt_, nnn_, mm1_, mm2_, 
   lim_Integer?Positive] := Module[{sh = s/2, k, p0, t},

   numpt = n;
   Print[StringForm[" `1` .", numpt], DateString[]];

   nnn1 = nnn; mmm1 = mm1; mmm2 = mm2; tt1 = tt; n10 = 100; nh1 = 100;
   no1 = 100;
   nh = 0; no = 0; n8 = 0; n9 = 0; n12 = 0; n14 = 0; n16 = 0;
   npt = 1;
   rad = {};
   Do[rad0 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 0.5]]; 
   If[rad0 >= 2 && rad0 <= 4, AppendTo[rad, rad0]]; 
   If[Length[rad] == numpt, Break[], Continue], {10 numpt}];

   p0 = {RandomReal[{-sh + r, 0 - r}], RandomReal[{-sh + r, sh - r}], 
   RandomReal[{-sh + r, sh - r}]};
   spl = {p0};

   k = 2;
   While[k <= numpt,
   Label[begin5]; 
   p0 = {RandomReal[{-sh + r, 0 - r}], RandomReal[{-sh + r, sh - r}],
   RandomReal[{-sh + r, sh - r}]};
   err1 = 0; err2 = 0;
   Do[dd1 = rad[[k]] + rad[[kk]]; dd = Max[dd1, 2.7]; 
   If[EuclideanDistance[p0, spl[[kk]]] >= dd, err1 = 0, err1 = 1]; 
   err2 += err1, {kk, 1, Length[spl]}];
   If[err2 == 0, AppendTo[spl, p0], Goto[begin5]]; 
   If[Mod[Length[spl], 100] == 
   0, {Print[StringForm[" `1` .", Length[spl]]]}]; ++k];
   Print[StringForm[" `1` Done. ", Length[spl]]];
   (**)

   hhpl = Table[{}, {tt}, {nnn}];
   hpl = Table[{}, {tt}];


   t = 1; While[t <= tt,
   Label[begin105];
   nn = 1; 
   While[nn <= nnn + 1 - t, 
   If[t > 1 && nn == 1, 
   Print[StringForm["hhpl[[t,1]] = `1` .", 
    Length[hhpl[[t - 1, nn]]]], DateString[]]];

   m = 1; Label[begin1]; 
   If[t > 1, {If[
    Length[hhpl[[t - 1, nn]]] == 
     0, {mmm1 = 0}, {mmm1 = Length[hhpl[[t - 1, nn]]]}]}]; 
   While[m <= mmm1, 
   If[t == 1, {ph = {-50, RandomReal[{-sh, sh}], 
      RandomReal[{-sh, sh}]}}, {hRandVector = 
     Normalize[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 3]]; nh++; 
    If[nh > nh1, {If[
       nh > 3 nh1, {Print[StringForm["001 nh = `1` .", nh]]; 
        ph = hhpl[[t - 1, nn, m]]; 
        Goto[begin37]}, {If[nh == 2 nh1, 
         Print[StringForm["002 nh = `1` .", nh]]]; 
        ph = {hhpl[[t - 1, nn, m, 1]] + hRandVector[[1]], 
          hhpl[[t - 1, nn, m, 2]] + hRandVector[[2]], 
          hhpl[[t - 1, nn, m, 3]] + hRandVector[[3]]}}]}, {If[
       nh == nh1, Print[StringForm["003 nh = `1` .", nh]]]; 
      ph = {hhpl[[t - 1, nn, m, 1]] + Abs[hRandVector[[1]]], 
        hhpl[[t - 1, nn, m, 2]] + hRandVector[[2]], 
        hhpl[[t - 1, nn, m, 3]] + hRandVector[[3]]}}]}];

    err1 = 0; err2 = 0; k = 1; 
    While[k <= Length[spl], 
    If[EuclideanDistance[ph, spl[[k]]] >= rad[[k]] + 1, err1 = 0, 
    err1 = 1]; err2 += err1; If[err2 != 0, Goto[begin1]]; k++]; 
    Label[begin37]; AppendTo[hhpl[[t, nn]], ph]; nh = 0;
    m++];
   nn++];

   i = 1; 
   While[i <= t, iijj = t + 1 - i; k = 1; 
   While[k <= Length[hhpl[[i, iijj]]], 
   AppendTo[hpl[[t]], hhpl[[i, iijj, k]]]; k++]; i++];
   t++];

   proGraph = 
   Graphics3D[{Lighter[Green], Sphere[spl, rad], Magenta, 
    Sphere[#, 1.2]}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
   Axes -> Automatic, 
   PlotRange -> {{-52, 2}, {-52, 52}, {-52, 52}}] & /@ hpl;
   (*-----------------------------Export Data-------------------------------
   ---------------------------------------------*)


  Export["spl.m", spl, "Package"];
  Label[begin27];
  Print[StringForm["All Done = `1` .", t - 1], DateString[]];
  ];
 sPa[s_, r_, n_Integer, tt_, nnn_, mm1_, mm2_] := 
 sPa[s, r, n, tt, nnn, mm1, mm2, Quotient[n, 1]]

 (*DistributeDefinitions[sPa,s,r, \
 tt,nnn,mm1,mm2,n,k,p0,t,sh,rad,spl,err1,err2];*)

 sPa[100, 1, 100, 50, 50, 12, 3]
 Parallelize[sPa]
```

There are some values in the last two lines, in my heavy code, I need to change some of them to be over 1000, but it will take more than a month, and sometimes the computer just dies because of no memory.

I really need some advice here to solve this problem. Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: There are quite a few issues with your code.  For example your second last line `sPa[100, 1, 100, 50, 50, 12, 3]` calls the function without any parallel kernels and your last line `Parallelize[sPa]` does nothing. I strongly suggest that you take some time to read the [Parallel Computing Tools User Guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ParallelTools/tutorial/Overview.html) to learn how parallel computing is performed in the Wolfram Language.  Also, your code is written procedural instead of functional which will make it slower; but that is another story.

Comment: Thank you @Edmund. I've read the Parallel Computing Tools User Guide when first tried. There is not many examples showing parallel computation when Module used. Is it possible to apply parallel computation to a Module?